# Bash script to create virtual clusters isn't working

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I am trying to create a script to create virtual clusters on my virtual machine which is a CentOS 7 minimal.

I got a script named `cluster`

```
#!/bin/bash

function vc
{
    echo
    echo -n "Enter project name: "
    read platform_name

    echo
    echo -n "web extension: "
    read web_extension

    echo
    echo -e "The following website will be created"
    echo -e "\e[32m Platform:\e[0m\t${platform_name}"
    echo -e "\e[32m Extension:\e[0m\t${web_extension}"
    echo -e "\e[32m Full URL:\e[0m\t http://www.${platform_name}.${web_extension}"

    echo
    echo -e "Do you wish to proceed? [Y/n]"
    read -p "Are you sure? " -n 1 -r
    echo    # (optional) move to a new line
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        echo
        echo -e "\e[32m Creating platform \e[0m\t"
    else
        echo
        echo -e "\e[32m Not creating platform \e[0m\t"

    fi
}

if [ -n "$(type -t $FUNCTION_NAME)" ] && [ "$(type -t $FUNCTION_NAME)" = 
function ];
then $FUNCTION_NAME $2; else help; fi
```

Then as far as I understood I just have to make it executable
`chmod +x cluster`

And after this I should make a syslink for it `ln -s cluster /bin/cluster` 
And now I should normally be able to just typ `cluster vc` in the terminal and it should execute the script but it keeps giving me "command cluster not found"

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Or do I need to use another chmod on it so I can run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolic link targets are resolved relative the the symlink location. In your case that means, if you run `/bin/cluster` it looks for a file named `cluster` (the target) in the `/bin/directory`. Either provide a relative path which points to your file or link to an absolute path: `ln -s /path/to/cluster /bin/cluster`.

Also make sure that the target location is readable and executable by whomever executes the symlink.

Comment: Thanks it seemed that all I needed to change was making sure to create the symlink with absolute paths